# Is it essential to integrate Facebook SDK to work with Mobile App Ads Install

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook, xcode5

I have used Mobile App Ads Install” to promote my app via “Facebook”, I can see the ads appearing within the “news feed section“ of the users but the issue is that :

Even if user installs the app , the ads appears again and again, how can I stop the occurrence of ads multiple times when user has installed the app once?

I believe this issue could negatively impact the app as Facebook's algorithm places a high negative penalty on the 'quality score' of apps that have high percentages of "X-outs" or spam complaints.

I have gone through the documentation specified at : “https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads/“ but I am confused about the steps to follow in order to "Exclude the people to show these ads who already have the app installed?"

Am I only required to specify the "fb+App_Id" in my apps Info.plist or I too need to write the two lines of code specified below ?

[FBSettings setDefaultAppID:YOUR_APP_ID];
[FBAppEvents activateApp];

Can some one please help me through this ?

Comment: You should do both. Adding the fb+App_Id in your plist will allow the facebook app to detect that your app is present on the device, whereas calling activateApp will give you insights information on app installs.

Comment: but I don't need the insight information of the installs ......I just need to stop the multiple ads coming on Facebook if I have the app already installed on the device.By just using Fb+App_Id will fulfill the above requirement or not ?

Answer (score 1):

I too was in search of this questions answer .......I have tried with a sample app using NSURLScheme and It seems using FB_App_ID is sufficient to exclude people who already have your app installed.There is no need to Install SDK.

Also Please refer the page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add both as adding the Fb+App_Id will just help the facebook app and your app to communicate, but the logic to send the install event back to facebook would lie somewhere in SDK.

If you will refer the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads/ and the respective Upgrade guides, you will find that, for sending the install event to facebook you need to integrate the sdk and specify this:

[FBSettings setDefaultAppID:YOUR_APP_ID]; 
[FBAppEvents activateApp];

Because if you will not do this then how facebook would come to know that the device had the app installed once ?

Answer (score 0):

You should also call `[FBAppEvents activateApp];` too. The [iOS SDK Doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.9/class/FBAppEvents/) doesn't provide much info what this method does. So I dig into [FBSDKAppEvents.h](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppEvents.h), and see some more interesting info...

> This method also takes care of logging the event indicating the first time this app has been launched, which, among other things, is
>   used to  track user acquisition and app install ads conversions.

See full method description below.

```
/*!
 @abstract
 Notifies the events system that the app has launched and, when appropriate, logs an "activated app" event.  Should typically be placed in the
 app delegates' `applicationDidBecomeActive:` method.
 This method also takes care of logging the event indicating the first time this app has been launched, which, among other things, is used to
 track user acquisition and app install ads conversions.
 @discussion
 `activateApp` will not log an event on every app launch, since launches happen every time the app is backgrounded and then foregrounded.
 "activated app" events will be logged when the app has not been active for more than 60 seconds.  This method also causes a "deactivated app"
 event to be logged when sessions are "completed", and these events are logged with the session length, with an indication of how much
 time has elapsed between sessions, and with the number of background/foreground interruptions that session had.  This data
 is all visible in your app's App Events Insights.
 */
+ (void)activateApp;
```